# Android Room Database - Batch Insert is not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I am using Room database in Android and trying to do batch insert in ENTITY or TABLE created in Room database Andorid.

I am trying as below :

```
suspend fun batchInsertDataToTable(listObjDetails: ArrayList<Data>) {
    try {
     appDatabase.myDao().insertAll(*listObjDetails.toTypedArray())

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Where, `myDao().insertAll()` method is as below :

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun insertAll(vararg objData: Data)
```

But, when I have checked the database, there is not entry in the table.

NOTE : I can do normal Insert in this table using for loop.

What might be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Insert function returns a Long as a return value. This number represent the amount of rows added to the db. First check if this nunber is 0.if it isn't 0 then the rows entered the db.

Comment: Also, try to remove tge IGNORE strategy to see if insertion fails due to conflicts.

Comment: @gioravered Its worked with REPLACE, But Is there any way that we can confirm that data inserted successfully or not with insertAll(). I have checked manually and its inserted.

Comment: As I said, insert returns a a nunber (long) that represents the number of rows added to the db. Change your signature to: suspend fun insertAll(vararg objData: Data): Long, and check that the returnd number is matching the size of the list.